# Hide/Display Table Row on Hover using Inline CSS/JS Only

Tags: javascript, css, hover, inline, styling

Sorry for the weird title... Here's what I'm trying to do. I have a table. On the table you will see a row that says "Contact Person for..." What I would like to happen is when the user hovers over the row that says "Contact Person For..." I would like for the cell beneath to become visible, but only while the row is being hovered on.

Here's the catch... I'm trying to spruce up an existing page with this, but the website uses a very limited CMS which doesn't allow for custom scripts or stylesheets, everything has to be inline. Is there anyway to accomplish what I would like?

Here's the code...

```
    <table border=1 style="display: inline-block;">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color: #660000; color: #FFFFFF"><strong>Person #1</strong><br />Person Title</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #e0e0eb">
      <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Line #1<br />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Line #2</p>
      <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;(###) ###-####</p>
      <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:email@email.com">person@email.com</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color: #660000; color: #FFFFFF;">Contact Person for...</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="background-color: #e0e0eb;">
      <ul>
        <li>Task #1</li>
        <li>Task #2</li>
        <li>Task #3</li>
        <li>Task #4</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it isn't clear what you mean by the cell beneath ? the 'contact for ' is itself a cell within that row. So, my question is what is in the cell beneath ??

Comment: can you please upload code snippet or fiddle? and also mention that where you want to hover that table row hide/display

Comment: Here is the jFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kryn798a/#&togetherjs=Bdr3zkw07q

I would like for the user to hover over the text that says "Contact Person For..." and when they do have the cell beneath that contains the text "Task #1 etc." to display, but only when the user is hovering over the "Contact Person For..." text.

Comment: inline css doesn't know `:hover`. You can do it only with stylesheet or javascript.